# C++ - cmake cannot find boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

For a project, I have to use cmake in combination with boost to generate a C++ build (avro). I have installed the following programs:

- cmake v3.4.3
- boost v1.55.0

But when executing the command with the following statements in the `.bat` file (this batch file got provided by a 3th party provider),

```
set BOOST_ROOT=D:\software\boost_1_55_0\
set BOOST_INCLUDEDIR=D:\software\boost_1_55_0\boost
set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=D:\software\boost_1_55_0\lib32-msvc-12.0

set PATH=%MSVS_HOME%\VC;%BOOST_LIBRARYDIR%;%BOOST_ROOT%;%BOOST_INCLUDEDIR%;%PATH%

call vcvarsall.bat

cmake .. -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

(remark: `MSVS_HOME` is the directory where Visual Studio got installed to and the other paths are set by my own.)
cmake throws up with errors, as shown here below

```
CMake Error at D:/software/cmake_3.4.3/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1247 (message):
 Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

 Boost version: 1.55.0

 Boost include path: D:/software/boost_1_55_0

 Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_filesystem
          boost_system
          boost_program_options

 No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
 directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:54 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/kaa/kaaBuild/avro-src-1.7.5/lang/c++/build.win/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

It however surprises me because in the boost directory, you can find the required libraries. Here below are PS commands that I have used to find the required Boost libraries.

```
PS D:\software\boost_1_55_0\lib32-msvc-12.0> Get-ChildItem boost_file* -name
boost_filesystem-vc120-1_55.dll
boost_filesystem-vc120-1_55.lib
boost_filesystem-vc120-gd-1_55.dll
boost_filesystem-vc120-gd-1_55.lib
boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_55.dll
boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_55.lib
boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.dll
boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib

PS D:\software\boost_1_55_0\lib32-msvc-12.0> Get-ChildItem boost_system* -name
boost_system-vc120-1_55.dll
boost_system-vc120-1_55.lib
boost_system-vc120-gd-1_55.dll
boost_system-vc120-gd-1_55.lib
boost_system-vc120-mt-1_55.dll
boost_system-vc120-mt-1_55.lib
boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.dll
boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib

PS D:\software\boost_1_55_0\lib32-msvc-12.0> Get-ChildItem boost_program_opt* -name
boost_program_options-vc120-1_55.dll
boost_program_options-vc120-1_55.lib
boost_program_options-vc120-gd-1_55.dll
boost_program_options-vc120-gd-1_55.lib
boost_program_options-vc120-mt-1_55.dll
boost_program_options-vc120-mt-1_55.lib
boost_program_options-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.dll
```

As you can see, the required file is available in the right location.

**Question :**
I am not familiar with cmake. Could the problem be at the cmake list (here below) or is the problem somewhere else ? I already have looked into the following questions:

- [c++ - cmake cannot find boost libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303430/cmake-cannot-find-boost-libraries)
  The answer goes about a configuration problem. But since I have barely experience with cmake, I am not sure if the configuration is correct. I didn't have configured it. These files got provided to me by a 3th party provider...
- [C++ - CMAKE cannot find boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930872/cmake-cannot-find-boost)
  There is no answer, but in the comment, it mentions about the variables. I have set it correctly here (I think ...)
- [Cmake doesn't find Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost)
  The answer tells to add those two lines before the `FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)` but my cmakelists.txt (here below) doesn't contain it.
- [C++ - CMake is not able to find boost libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173330/cmake-is-not-able-to-find-boost-libraries)
  The answers were vague, I don't know which one would be useful. There is an answer that mentions a snippet which can be added to the `cmakelists.txt`. I'm not sure if I should do that. (As said, the files got provided by a 3th party provider)

I have also checked the following answers outside StackOverflow:

- [this](http://ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=65679), which tells about the environment variables, something what I already have
- [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551876/cmake-3-0-2-cant-find-boost-on-14-04), it mentions about a version of libdev boost. I do think that I have the latest version. (see above, I have Boost 1.55)
- [this](http://www.orocos.org/forum/orocos/orocos-users/cmake-cannot-find-boost-libraries), that mentions to remove the cmake file. However, it works for orocos, something that I don't use. I don't think that this wouldn't solve my problem either. But I tried it anyways, and no, didn't helped.

**So, what can I do to solve this problem ?** Did I have overlooked on something ? Missed something important ?

There are two snippets here below, the cmake list and the cmake log, generated after the aboved failed execution. I hope that these are useful.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

set (CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 0)

if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS_NO_WARNINGS)
    set (CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS_NO_WARNINGS ON)
endif()

if (EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/VERSION.txt)
    file(READ "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/VERSION.txt" AVRO_VERSION)
else (EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/VERSION.txt)
    file(READ "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../share/VERSION.txt"
        AVRO_VERSION)
endif (EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/VERSION.txt)

set (AVRO_VERSION_MAJOR ${AVRO_VERSION})
set (AVRO_VERSION_MINOR "0")

project (Avro-cpp)

if (WIN32 AND NOT CYGWIN AND NOT MSYS)
add_definitions (/EHa)
add_definitions (
    -DBOOST_REGEX_DYN_LINK
    -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK
    -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK
    -DBOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_DYN_LINK
    -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)
endif()

if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")
endif ()


find_package (Boost 1.38 REQUIRED
    COMPONENTS filesystem system program_options)

add_definitions (${Boost_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC_DEFINITIONS})

include_directories (api ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set (AVRO_SOURCE_FILES
        impl/Compiler.cc impl/Node.cc
        impl/NodeImpl.cc impl/ResolverSchema.cc impl/Schema.cc
        impl/Types.cc impl/ValidSchema.cc impl/Zigzag.cc
        impl/BinaryEncoder.cc impl/BinaryDecoder.cc
        impl/Stream.cc impl/FileStream.cc
        impl/Generic.cc
        impl/DataFile.cc
        impl/parsing/Symbol.cc
        impl/parsing/ValidatingCodec.cc
        impl/parsing/JsonCodec.cc
        impl/parsing/ResolvingDecoder.cc
        impl/json/JsonIO.cc
        impl/json/JsonDom.cc
        impl/Resolver.cc impl/Validator.cc
        )

add_library (avrocpp SHARED ${AVRO_SOURCE_FILES})

set_property (TARGET avrocpp
    APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS AVRO_DYN_LINK)

add_library (avrocpp_s STATIC ${AVRO_SOURCE_FILES})

set_property (TARGET avrocpp avrocpp_s
    APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS AVRO_SOURCE)

set_target_properties (avrocpp PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${AVRO_VERSION_MAJOR}.${AVRO_VERSION_MINOR})

set_target_properties (avrocpp_s PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${AVRO_VERSION_MAJOR}.${AVRO_VERSION_MINOR})

target_link_libraries (avrocpp ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

add_executable (precompile test/precompile.cc)

target_link_libraries (precompile avrocpp_s ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

macro (gencpp file ns)
    add_custom_command (OUTPUT ${ns}.hh
        COMMAND precompile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jsonschemas/${file}
            ${file}
        COMMAND python ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/gen-cppcode.py
            -n ${ns} -i ${file} -o ${ns}.hh
        DEPENDS precompile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jsonschemas/${file})
    add_custom_target(${ns} DEPENDS ${ns}.hh)
endmacro (gencpp)

if (CYGWIN OR NOT WIN32)
    gencpp (bigrecord testgen)
    gencpp (bigrecord2 testgen2)
endif ()

macro (gen file ns)
    add_custom_command (OUTPUT ${file}.hh
        COMMAND avrogencpp
            -p -
            -i ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jsonschemas/${file}
            -o ${file}.hh -n ${ns} -U
        DEPENDS avrogencpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jsonschemas/${file})
    add_custom_target (${file}_hh DEPENDS ${file}.hh)
endmacro (gen)

gen (bigrecord testgen)
gen (bigrecord2 testgen2)
gen (tweet testgen3)
gen (union_array_union uau)
gen (union_map_union umu)
gen (union_conflict uc)
gen (recursive rec)
gen (reuse ru)
gen (circulardep cd)

add_executable (avrogencpp impl/avrogencpp.cc)
target_link_libraries (avrogencpp avrocpp_s ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

enable_testing()

macro (unittest name)
    add_executable (${name} test/${name}.cc)
    target_link_libraries (${name} avrocpp ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    add_test (NAME ${name} WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${name})
endmacro (unittest)

unittest (buffertest)
unittest (unittest)
unittest (SchemaTests)
unittest (CodecTests)
unittest (StreamTests)
unittest (SpecificTests)
unittest (DataFileTests)
unittest (JsonTests)
unittest (AvrogencppTests)

if (CYGWIN OR NOT WIN32)
    unittest (testgentest)
    add_dependencies (testgentest testgen testgen2)
endif()

add_dependencies (AvrogencppTests bigrecord_hh bigrecord2_hh tweet_hh
    union_array_union_hh union_map_union_hh union_conflict_hh
    recursive_hh reuse_hh circulardep_hh)

include (InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)

set (CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "avrocpp-${AVRO_VERSION_MAJOR}")

include (CPack)

install (TARGETS avrocpp avrocpp_s
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION lib)

install (TARGETS avrogencpp RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

install (DIRECTORY api/ DESTINATION include/avro
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN *.hh)

if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING
      "Choose the type of build, options are: None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo MinSizeRel."
      FORCE)
endif (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
```

and the cmake log:

```
The system is: Windows - 10.0.10586 - AMD64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

CMakeCCompilerId.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:CMakeCCompilerId.exe 
CMakeCCompilerId.obj 


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "CMakeCCompilerId.exe"

Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "CMakeCCompilerId.obj"

The C compiler identification is MSVC, found in "D:/kaa/kaaBuild/avro-src-1.7.5/lang/c++/build.win/CMakeFiles/3.4.3/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.exe"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe 
CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj 


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"

Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CMakeCXXCompilerId.obj"

The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in "D:/kaa/kaaBuild/avro-src-1.7.5/lang/c++/build.win/CMakeFiles/3.4.3/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.exe"

Determining if the C compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/kaa/kaaBuild/avro-src-1.7.5/lang/c++/build.win/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_279c3\fast"
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_279c3.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_279c3.dir\build

Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_279c3.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

    C:\PROGRA~2\VISUAL~1.0\VC\bin\cl.exe  @C:\Users\geire\AppData\Local\Temp\nm8C78.tmp

testCCompiler.c

Linking C executable cmTC_279c3.exe

    D:\software\cmake_3.4.3\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_279c3.dir --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\VISUAL~1.0\VC\bin\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_279c3.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\geire\AppData\Local\Temp\nm8DF0.tmp



Detecting C compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/kaa/kaaBuild/avro-src-1.7.5/lang/c++/build.win/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_f6e85\fast"
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_f6e85.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_f6e85.dir\build

Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f6e85.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.obj

    C:\PROGRA~2\VISUAL~1.0\VC\bin\cl.exe  @C:\Users\geire\AppData\Local\Temp\nm908F.tmp

CMakeCCompilerABI.c

Linking C executable cmTC_f6e85.exe

    D:\software\cmake_3.4.3\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_f6e85.dir --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\VISUAL~1.0\VC\bin\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_f6e85.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\geire\AppData\Local\Temp\nm90CF.tmp



Determining if the CXX compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/kaa/kaaBuild/avro-src-1.7.5/lang/c++/build.win/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_38c4b\fast"
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_38c4b.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_38c4b.dir\build

Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_38c4b.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj

    C:\PROGRA~2\VISUAL~1.0\VC\bin\cl.exe  @C:\Users\geire\AppData\Local\Temp\nm92E1.tmp

testCXXCompiler.cxx

Linking CXX executable cmTC_38c4b.exe

    D:\software\cmake_3.4.3\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_38c4b.dir --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\VISUAL~1.0\VC\bin\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_38c4b.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\geire\AppData\Local\Temp\nm9330.tmp



Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/kaa/kaaBuild/avro-src-1.7.5/lang/c++/build.win/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_c9164\fast"
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_c9164.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_c9164.dir\build

Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c9164.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.obj

    C:\PROGRA~2\VISUAL~1.0\VC\bin\cl.exe  @C:\Users\geire\AppData\Local\Temp\nm95DE.tmp

CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp

Linking CXX executable cmTC_c9164.exe

    D:\software\cmake_3.4.3\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_c9164.dir --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\VISUAL~1.0\VC\bin\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_c9164.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\geire\AppData\Local\Temp\nm962E.tmp





Detecting CXX [] compiler features compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/kaa/kaaBuild/avro-src-1.7.5/lang/c++/build.win/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_2af8b\fast"
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_2af8b.dir\build.make /nologo -L                  CMakeFiles\cmTC_2af8b.dir\build

Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_2af8b.dir/feature_tests.cxx.obj

    C:\PROGRA~2\VISUAL~1.0\VC\bin\cl.exe  @C:\Users\geire\AppData\Local\Temp\nm98CC.tmp

feature_tests.cxx

Linking CXX executable cmTC_2af8b.exe

    D:\software\cmake_3.4.3\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_2af8b.dir --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\VISUAL~1.0\VC\bin\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_2af8b.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\geire\AppData\Local\Temp\nm992B.tmp



    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_alias_templates
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_alignas
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_alignof
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_attributes
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_attribute_deprecated
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_auto_type
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_binary_literals
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_constexpr
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_contextual_conversions
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_decltype
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_decltype_auto
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_default_function_template_args
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_defaulted_functions
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_defaulted_move_initializers
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_delegating_constructors
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_deleted_functions
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_digit_separators
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_enum_forward_declarations
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_explicit_conversions
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_extended_friend_declarations
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_extern_templates
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_final
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_func_identifier
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_generalized_initializers
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_generic_lambdas
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_inheriting_constructors
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_inline_namespaces
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_lambdas
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_lambda_init_captures
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_local_type_template_args
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_long_long_type
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_noexcept
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_nonstatic_member_init
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_nullptr
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_override
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_range_for
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_raw_string_literals
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_reference_qualified_functions
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_return_type_deduction
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_right_angle_brackets
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_rvalue_references
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_sizeof_member
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_static_assert
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_strong_enums
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_template_template_parameters
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_thread_local
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_trailing_return_types
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_unicode_literals
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_uniform_initialization
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_unrestricted_unions
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_user_literals
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_variadic_macros
    Feature record: CXX_FEATURE:1cxx_variadic_templates
```

Comment: You have Visual Studio 14.0 in your system but the Boost was built with MSVC 12.0. CMake is looking for the Boost compiled with the same MSVC version and cannot find it.

Comment: @EvgenyS. I have rebuild the boost myself. I also have ensured that i have the latest builds and I still get the same issue :/

Comment: So. now you have boost vc140 on the path? BOOST_ROOT must point to the library where you put the boost with building the boost and running install. Usually on windows it contains 2 folders: include and lib. In include there is something like boost-1_55, in lib there is a list of lib and dll files. BOOST_LIBRARYDIR must point to that lib folder. I looked through my scripts - usually I don't use the BOOST_INCLUDEDIR. And you can change boost version to 1.55 in `find_package(Boost` in your `CMakeLists.txt` but it shouldn't matter.